# Show that $p^3 \mid (r^{p(p-1)} - 1) \Rightarrow p^2 \mid (r^{p-1}-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p \nmid r$ is an odd prime, show
$$p^3 \mid (r^{p(p-1)} - 1) \Rightarrow p^2 \mid (r^{p-1}-1)$$

---

My attempt:

$$r^{p(p-1)}-1 = (\color{red}{r^{p-1}-1})(\color{blue}{r^{(p-1)(p-1)} +r^{(p-1)(p-2)} + \cdots +  r^{(p-1)2 }+r^{p-1}+1}) = \color{red}{X}\color{blue}{Y}$$

$p \mid \color{red}{X}$ by Euler,
and $\color{blue}{Y} \equiv (\underbrace{1+1+\cdots}_{p-1\text{ times}})+1  =p\equiv 0 \pmod p$.
So the right hand side  $\color{red}{X}\color{blue}{Y}$ is divisible by $p^2$.
How to show the other $p$  ***doesn't***  divide  $\color{blue}{Y}$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $r$ is a primitive root of $p$ and $p^2$, then show that it is also a primitive root of $p^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248066/if-r-is-a-primitive-root-of-p-and-p2-then-show-that-it-is-also-a-primiti)

Comment: @user10354138  that question  was also posted by me a few minutes back... the approach in that answer is good but I feel this is a different question somehow. If possible I'm trying to finish the proof using the method described in current question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can note that
$$
Y=(r^{p-1}-1)[(r^{p-1})^{p-2}+2(r^{p-1})^{p-3}+\dots+(p-2)r^{p-1}+(p-1)]+p.
$$
Clearly $p\mid (r^{p-1}-1)$, and the term inside square bracket is, modulo $p$, the same as $1+2+\dots+(p-1)=p\frac{p-1}2=0$ so you get $Y\equiv p\pmod{p^2}$.

Comment: $Y = p^2m + p$ so $Y \equiv p \not \equiv 0  \pmod{p^2}$ You're awesome! I still have to make sense of that factorization...  thank you so much again XD

Answer (score 2):

I don't offhand see any way to use what you did to prove the result. Instead, [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) shows that

$$r^{p-1} = ap + 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

for some integer $a$. This then gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(r^{p-1}\right)^{p} - 1 & = (ap + 1)^{p} - 1 \\
& = (ap)^p + p(ap)^{p-1} + \ldots + \frac{p(p-1)}{2}(ap)^2 + p(ap) + 1 - 1 \\
& = p^2\left(a^{p}p^{p-2} + a^{p-1}p^{p-2} + \ldots + \frac{p-1}{2}(a^2)(p) + a \right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note every term inside the brackets has a factor of $p$ except for the last one, i.e., $a$. Since $p^3 \mid (r^{p(p-1)} - 1)$, this means $p \mid a$. Thus, \eqref{eq1A} gives that

$$p^2 \mid r^{p-1} - 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$